# Matching dictionaries with columns and indices in DataFrame | python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame with column names as on  example and the indices from 0 to 1000. The dataframe is filled with zeros.

```
House 1 | House 2 | House 5 | House 8 | ...
0
1
2
3
4...
```

Then, I have dictionary, e.g.:

```
dict_of_houses = {'House 1':[100,201,306,387,500,900],'House 2':[31,87,254,675,987],'House 5':[23,45,67,123,345,654,789,808,864,987,999],'House 8':[23,675,786,858,868,912,934]}
```

*Dictionary name edited in order not to confuse anyone later.*

My goal is to:

- for every dict key match it with the column
- for every number in the list as dictionary value to match with the index
- if there is a match of index and column, then change the cell to 1
- else: leave zero

How would you do that?

Comment: Side note: never (even in an example) name variables after built-ins, e.g. use `dict_` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for house, indices in dict_.items():
    df.loc[indices, house] = 1
```